# How to convert variable (object) name into String

Tags: string, r, object

I have the following data frame with variable name `"foo"`;

```
 > foo <-c(3,4);
```

What I want to do is to convert `"foo"` into a string. So that in a function
I don't have to recreate another extra variables:

```
   output <- myfunc(foo)
   myfunc <- function(v1) {
     # do something with v1
     # so that it prints "FOO" when 
     # this function is called 
     #
     # instead of the values (3,4)
     return ()
   }
```

Comment: Just curious - why do you need to get object name from an object?

Comment: I have a sample use:  I have a function that takes as argument a vector, and append the values of that vector into a column in a dataframe. I also need to populate into another column the source of the value, which is the name of the initial vector. Voila.

Comment: To use `exists()` which requires a string.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil It may be useful to pass the string name of the object to its output file name, for instance.

Comment: My two cents: a plotting function using the given variable names as labels / legend

Answer (score 313, accepted):

You can use `deparse` and `substitute` to get the name of a function argument:

```
myfunc <- function(v1) {
  deparse(substitute(v1))
}

myfunc(foo)
[1] "foo"
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the helpful answer, what about if I pass `foo[1]`; is there a way to get just "foo" back?

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha You can try this function: `myfunc <- function(v1) {
  s <- substitute(v1);
  if (length(s) == 1)
    deparse(s)
  else
    sub("\\(.", "", s[2])
}`.

Comment: How would you do this with multiple objects? Specifically, how would you do it in a way to get separate strings for each object name?  (For example, if I had object foo, foo1, and foo2 and I wanted to create a list of their names as separate character strings).

Comment: @theforestecologist If the function has multiple parameters, you can use `deparse(substitute(.))` for each parameter, store the result in a variable, and put the variables in a list afterwards.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein this doesn't work when you use a for loop...

Comment: you can also use deparse(quote(var)) in which quote freeze the var from evaluation and deparse which is the inverse of parse make the symbol back to string

Comment: @theforestecologist the best I've found is  : `unlist(strsplit(gsub("^.*\\(|\\)|\\s","", deparse(substitute(x))), ","))`

Comment: actually see : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names/16951524#16951524) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names/16951524#16951524)