# r get variable name that has maximum

Tags: r, variables, max, names

I've searched online for a while now but not really finding answers to this specific question. 
maybe im not using the right key words... but if there's already a thread on this question, please direct me to it!

so let's say the data looks like this:

`a = 3
b = 5`

now i want to find out which one is larger, so i do:

```
max(a,b)
```

this will only return me the "5", but i want it to return "b"
i tried using which() but it keep saying "which is not logical"
i also tried deparse() but i get a string of "5"

thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

thanks andrewelamb for a great start on the answer. 
i changed the code a bit to produce the right answer i was looking for:

```
`a = 3
 b = 5
 v_name = ["a","b"]
 v_name[which.max(c(a,b))]`
```

hope it helps anyone else who has this problem as well in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- 5
b <- 4
vector <- c(a,b)
which.max(vector)
vector[which.max(vector)]
```

Comment: thank you very much! one thing i'd like to point out is, the a & b passed into the vector should be strings. but when passing into the which.max() should be numbers.

Comment: I misunderstood, I think John's got it above

Answer (score 0):

[A basic approach to get variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14577878/1566267) is implemented as `myfunc`, everything else is concise:

```
myfunc <- function(v1) {
  deparse(substitute(v1))
}
a=3
b=5
ifelse(max(a,b),myfunc(a),myfunc(b))
```

Comment: what an interesting way to approach this. :)

Comment: However, both approaches need one element for each variable to be defined. My: `myfunc(variable)` (conditional function call), yours: `"variable"` (in vector) ;)