# histogram with user defined function in R

Tags: r, function, histogram

Suppose I have written a user defined function to create a histogram:

```
sunny <- function(x,nadia) {
attach(nadia)
hist(x,  main="x", col="sea green", border="white",breaks=100)
}
```

Now my problem is I would like to have the variable name displayed on the graph, which is not appearing. I tried with the `main = option` but is it is showing only the character `x` since it is in quotes. I would be really glad if some one could solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly your question can be answerd by use of the answer on the following stack overflow question:[How to convert variable (object) name into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string)

Applied in your situation results in the following code:

```
sunny <- function(x,nadia) {
attach(nadia)
hist(x,  main=deparse(substitute(x)), col="sea green", border="white",breaks=100)
}
```

Comment: Great help. Thanks a lot for such a prompt response!!

Comment: This may be correct answer to the question but you should add some clarifications to it. Simply posting a code snippet without any explanation is not considered good practice here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic I edited my explenation, sorry for the confusion.