# Input variable name handling in R

Tags: r, input, variable-names

I would like to learn about how to handle an input of a variable name in a function. For example, I have written a function like this:

```
bin_multi <- function(y, dataframe, sel = NULL){
  if(!is.null(sel)) {
     dataframe <- dataframe[,sel]}
  else {
     dataframe <- dataframe[!y]}
}
```

Where `dataframe` is the input dataframe, `y` is the target variable in the dataframe, `sel` is the selection of columns from `dataframe`, for example, `sel = c(1,2,3)`.

The purpose of this function is to simply take a subset of `dataframe` with a given `sel`, and when `sel` is not given, exclude `y` the target variable from the `dataframe`.

My question is, how could I refer properly to `y` in this function? In the input, `y` is the name of a variable. Could `deparse()` solve this problem?

Thank you all.

Comment: Enter y as a character vector and then use `grep` or `grepl`: `dataframe <- dataframe[!grepl(y, names(dataframe), fixed=TRUE)]`.

Comment: @lmo Thanks! But if not enter y as a character? Because this is only a small part of the full function and if y is entered as a character then it would get messier in the rest.

Comment: It is unclear to me how it would get messier, but a simple solution would be to make a copy of y at the top of the function and use this throughout: `myY <- dataframe[, y]`. Then replace y with myY in your code.

Comment: @lmo Yeah that works too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
bin_multi <- function(y, dataframe, sel = NULL){

  if(!is.null(sel)) {

     dataframe <- dataframe[,sel]

  } else {

     dataframe <- dataframe[,which(names(dataframe) != deparse(substitute(y)))]

  }

}
```

That's drawing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string) to turn your object name into a string.

Comment: Thanks! I had `deparse(substitute(y))` but I did not use `which(names(.))` not including `y`. This is exactly how I want it to work!