# How to convert object variable into string inside a function

Tags: r

I have the following list of vectors

```r
v1 <-  c("foo","bar")
v2 <-  c("qux","uip","lsi")

mylist <- list(v1,v2)

mylist
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "foo" "bar"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "qux" "uip" "lsi"
```

What I want to do is to apply a function so that it prints the this string:

```r
v1:foo,bar
v2:qux,uip,lsi
```

So it involves two step: 1) Convert object variable to string and 
2) make the vector into string. The latter is easy as I can do this:

```r
make_string <- function (content_vector) {
  cat(content_vector,sep=",") 
}

make_string(mylist[[1]])
# foo,bar
make_string(mylist[[2]])
# qux,uip,lsi
```

I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14577878), but I don't know how can I turn the object name into a string *within a function* so that 
it prints like my desired output.

I need to to this inside a function, because there are many other output I need to process.

Comment: But where is 'v1' in the `make_string` function argument

Comment: @akrun That's why I post. I don't know how could I turn `v1 and v2` into string inside `make_string`.

Comment: okay, then we need to pass 'v1' and 'v2' bcz when you pass `mylist[[1]]` there is no 'v1'

Comment: @akrun Yes but as object not string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
cat(paste(c('v1', 'v2'), sapply(mylist, toString), sep=":", collapse="\n"), '\n')
#v1:foo, bar
#v2:qux, uip, lsi
```

---

If we need to pass the original object i.e. 'v1', 'v2'

```
make_string <- function(vec){
    obj <- deparse(substitute(vec))

    paste(obj, toString(vec), sep=":")
} 

make_string(v1)
#[1] "v1:foo, bar"
```

Comment: in your method `v1` and `v2` is hard coded as string. But I need to convert from object to string.

Comment: @pdubois  DId you meant to assign it to two vector objects

Comment: I mean I need `v1, v2` to be passed as object not string. See my update.

Comment: Great. Thanks a million. Last question. How can I use purrr to apply `make_string` for all object in `mylist`?

Comment: @pdubois But, in that case, there should be some indication of `v1', `v2`, as of now, there is nothing in mylist that relates to the original objects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a list, you can name the objects in the list to be able to use them in a function. Remove the `cat` if you just want a string to be returned.

```
v1 <-  c("foo","bar")
v2 <-  c("qux","uip","lsi")

# objects given names here
mylist <- list("v1" = v1, "v2" = v2)

# see names now next to the $
mylist
$v1
[1] "foo" "bar"

$v2
[1] "qux" "uip" "lsi"

make_string <- function (content_vector) {
    vecname <- names(content_vector)
    cat(paste0(vecname, ":", paste(sapply(content_vector, toString), sep = ",")))
}

make_string(mylist[1])
v1:foo, bar

make_string(mylist[2])
v2:qux, uip, lsi
```