# converting function calls to characters in R

Tags: r, function

I have a much more complicated function but the minimal version of it boils down to the following where I need to convert the entered function by the user to a character. But I can't figure out how to do this (I've also tried a bunch of `rlang` hacks that didn't work).

```r
foo <- function(.f) {
  if (as.character(.f) == "stats::lm") {
    print("this is lm")
  } else {
    print("this is not lm")
  }
}

foo(stats::lm)
#> Error in as.character(.f): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this would work?

```
    deparse(substitute(stats::lm))
[1] "stats::lm"
```

so using your function:

```
> foo <- function(.f) {
+   if (deparse(substitute(.f)) == "stats::lm") {
+     print("this is lm")
+   } else {
+     print("this is not lm")
+   }
+ }
> 
> foo(stats::lm)
[1] "this is lm"
```

Comment: useful info gained from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14577878/1317221

Answer (score 4):

You can use `identical` to compare the argument `.f` with the function you are interested in:

```r
foo <- function(.f) {
    if (identical(.f, stats::lm)) {
        print("this is lm")
    } else {
        print("this is not lm")
    }
}

foo(stats::lm)
#> [1] "this is lm"
```

The issue with the original approach is that `as.character(sum)` or any type of `as.character(fx)` does not mean anything to R. You can use `substitute(.f) == quote(stats::lm)` as well. Mainly, we need to intercept `.f` before it is evaluated and returns a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` option using `enquo` and `as_label`:

```
foo <- function(.f) {
.f <- enquo(.f)
  if (!!as_label(.f) == "stats::lm") {
    print("this is lm")
  } else {
    print("this is not lm")
  }
}

> foo(stats::lm)
[1] "this is lm"
```