# Call a variable name within another variable in R

Tags: r, string, function, reference

I have a variable:

```
Person1 = "friend"
```

That I save in a second variable, namely:

```
Real_friend = Person1
```

Is it possible to have a function like this:

```
   output <- myfunc(Real_friend)
   myfunc <- function(v1) {
     # do something with v1
     # so that it prints "Person1" when 
     # this function is called 
     #
     # instead of "friend"
     return ()
   }

output = "Person1"
```

I have tried to apply the method: deparse(substitute(v1)) suggested here:

[How to convert variable (object) name into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string)

but it does not seem to work.
Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `Real_friend = Person1`, R just puts the contents of Person1 into Real_friend, it doesn't save any record that this was done by way of Person1. One thing you could do, is to pass `"Person1"` to Real_friend, and then either call on `Real_friend` when you need `"Person1`" as the output, or call on `get(Real_Friend)` when you want the contents of Person1.

```
Person1<-"John"
> Real_friend<-"Person1"
> Real_friend
[1] "Person1"
> get(Real_friend)
[1] "John"
```

A second way of achieving something similar, using the link you provided, is to do:

```
> Real_friend<-substitute(Person1)
```

Now the contents of `Real_friend` are the unevaluated call for `Person1`:

```
> Real_friend
Person1
```

You can get the name of the variable as a string using `deparse`, or you can get the content of the variable using `eval`:

```
> deparse(Real_friend)
[1] "Person1"
> eval(Real_friend)
[1] "John"
```

Again, none of these options allows you to start with `Real_friend<-Person1`.