# How to convert variable name into string when the variables are stored in a list

Tags: r, type-conversion, variable-names

So there is a similar question on [How to convert variable (object) name into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string) using `deparse(substitute(variable))` but the solution  **doesn't work when variables are stored in a list**.

Example :

```
# I want to convert mtcars into a string ("mtcars")
data(mtcars, Titanic)
li = list(mtcars, Titanic)
varName = deparse(substitute(li[1])) # "li[1]" instead of "mtcars"
```

thank you!

Comment: The `li` doesn't have any information when you pass an object with value only.  You can create a named list and use `names(li)` or use `li <- dplyr::lst(mtcars, Titanic); names(li)`

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your help!