# How do I create a variable that tells me which of a number of other variables is the first one to not have a missing value for one observation?

Tags: r, variables, na

If I have the following data structure in my data frame df:

```
a  b  c  d

1  2  3  4
NA NA 1  2
NA 1  2  NA
NA NA NA 1
```

how can I create a variable that tells me, which of the variables is the first one to not have a missing value, such that:

```
a  b  c  d  var

1  2  3  4  a
NA NA 1  2  c
NA 1  2  NA b
NA NA NA 1  d
```

I need the code to work with variable names and not column numbers, because of the size of the dataset and changing the order of the variables.

I have tried:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var = coalesce(deparse(substitute(a)), deparse(substitute(b)), deparse(substitute(c)), deparse(substitute(d))))
```

and

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var = deparse(substitute(do.call(coalesce, across(c(a, b, c, d))))))
```

trying to implement this approach. I got the code to extract the string of a variable name from:
[How to convert variable (object) name into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col`, i.e.

```
names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = 'first')]
#[1] "a" "c" "b" "d"
```

Via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(var = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.), ties.method = 'first')])

   a  b  c  d var
1  1  2  3  4   a
2 NA NA  1  2   c
3 NA  1  2 NA   b
4 NA NA NA  1   d
```

You can specify variables

```
df %>% 
 mutate(var = names(.[c('a', 'b')])[max.col(!is.na(.[c('a', 'b')]), ties.method = 'first')])
   a  b  c  d var
1  1  2  3  4   a
2 NA NA  1  2   a
3 NA  1  2 NA   b
4 NA NA NA  1   a
```

You can also change the order of the variables via `select()`, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 select(c, d, b, a) %>%
 mutate(new = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.), ties.method = 'first')])

   c  d  b  a new
1  3  4  2  1   c
2  1  2 NA NA   c
3  2 NA  1 NA   c
4 NA  1 NA NA   d
```

You can also call `select()` again to restore the original order of columns but maintain the result from previous order, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 select(c, d, b, a) %>%
 mutate(new = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.), ties.method = 'first')]) %>% 
 select(names(df), new)

   a  b  c  d new
1  1  2  3  4   c
2 NA NA  1  2   c
3 NA  1  2 NA   c
4 NA NA NA  1   d
```

To maintain all the variables at the end, you can join on the original data frame, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 select(c, d, b) %>%
 mutate(new = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.), ties.method = 'first')]) %>% 
 left_join(df) %>% 
 select(names(df), new)

Joining, by = c("c", "d", "b")
   a  b  c  d new
1  1  2  3  4   c
2 NA NA  1  2   c
3 NA  1  2 NA   c
4 NA NA NA  1   d
```

Comment: How can I adapt this code if I want to check only certain variables in my data frame and if I want to be able to change the order in which they are checked for missing values?

Comment: I edited for specifying variables. The second inquiry you made about the order I don't understand what you mean

Comment: For example, if I want to check which variable is the first one to not have a missing value but not a, b, c, d but instead maybe c, b, a, d.

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know

Comment: This definitely works, the only issue is that I have other variables in the data frame that get lost if I take this approach. Maybe there is a way such that I have the original dataset in the end but with the additional variable ```new```?

Comment: See last update

Comment: ```df %>% 
 select(c, d, b) %>%
 mutate(new = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.), ties.method = 'first')]) %>% 
 select(new) %>% cbind(df) ``` appears to do the trick for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```r
df %>% mutate(var = apply(., 1, \(x) names(which(!is.na(x)))[1]))
#>    a  b  c  d var
#> 1  1  2  3  4   a
#> 2 NA NA  1  2   c
#> 3 NA  1  2 NA   b
#> 4 NA NA NA  1   d
```

Comment: How can I adapt this code if I want to change the order of the variables that are going to be checked for missing values, without changing the structure of the data frame?

Comment: You would change the order of the columns in `select` first.